# Cyberduck Error "Login Failed"

Tags: ssh, cyberduck

Exhausted available authentication methods. Please contact your web hosting service provider for assistance.

I continue to receive this error on Cyberduck. I was able to log into the account when I first downloaded Cyberduck. When I was finished with my work I saved/ closed everything, and it was so far so good. I hadn't logged out of the account. But since I have been trying to log back in I have been receiving this error.

Please help.

Comment: Hi Janie, welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried contacting your web hosting service provider for assistance?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Mac, try removing the application password from Keychain. There's a possibility that the old password is corrupted.

For me, my password was set to "`$this->request()`". So no matter what I type when connecting, Cyberduck used this "old" password.

Comment: This was the solution for me. By default cyber duck has checked add to keychain, so if credentials change or user/pw, it will under the hood apply the keychain and ignore what you put in there.

Answer (score 0):

You use Cyberduck to connect to an FTP server right?

If it's at all possible that anyone else has access to this account and failed to login a magical number of times (usually 3) then the server may have locked your account and needs to be restarted.

Or something is wrong with the server itself.

I hate to say it but contacting whoever is in charge of the server, as it said, is probably best. Without more information there's no way to know what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm using an SFTP server, if that makes a difference? Unless it's the same thing? How would the account be restarted?

Comment: @JanieLee  Contact your web hosting provider! I'm guessing the only reason you aren't able to access the server directly is because some company hosts your website for you. Unless there is information being withheld I can't possibly imagine a solution that doesn't run through that party.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to remove the application password but it kept failing to connect.
The solution was simply to remove and re-install the app.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was passing the username wrong.
I typed ununtu instead of ubuntu.

Check you server details you entered.